# SignalR - Send message OnConnected

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I've been experimenting with SignalR today and It's really neat. Basically what I wanted to achieve is the following:

As soon as a device connects it should send a message to the first one. If there are more devices than 1 connected I would like to send two messages. One to all **except** the last connected client. And one message to **only** the last connected client.

The code I've been using works perfect when I place it in a custom API controller and basically call the action, but that's not what I want.

I would like to send the messages as soon as a device connects within `OnConnected` without any user interaction, but when I place my code inside the `OnConnected` override it stops working. It doesn't send to the specific clients anymore (first connected and last connected).

I hope someone is able to help me out with this, because I've been banging my head for a few hours now.

```
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId, UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Count + 1);

        int amountOfConnections = UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Count;
        var lastConnection = UserHandler.ConnectedIds.OrderBy(x => x.Value).LastOrDefault();
        var allExceptLast = UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Take(amountOfConnections - 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

        if (amountOfConnections == 1)
        {
            Clients.Client(UserHandler.ConnectedIds.First().Key).hello("Send to only(also first) one");
        }
        else
        {
            Clients.Clients(allExceptLast).hello("Send to everyone except last");
            Clients.Client(lastConnection.Key).hello("Send to only the last one");
        }

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for all the help (upvoted you guys). Actually found the problem.. it was inside my client. I first subscribed to the 'hello' function and after that I started the HubConnection. As soon as I changed this order everything worked fine.

It worked with the following client code:

```
    private async Task ConnectToSignalR()
    {
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("url");
        hubConnection.Headers["x-zumo-application"] = "clientapikey";

        IHubProxy proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");

        proxy.On<string>("hello", async (msg) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        });

        await hubConnection.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

Unless I miss something from your question, the solution looks pretty simple to me, you just need to switch to using

```
Clients.Caller.hello("Send to only the last one");
```

instead of trying to understand yourself who's the last connected id. Same for the other ones, you can use:

```
Clients.Others.hello("Send to everyone except last");
```

You do not need all the logic you setup, those 2 lines do what you need, and they work inside `OnConnected`.

Comment: thanks a lot for this code. It actually makes my code a lot easier!

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't established a connection yet, trying to call your client `.hello()` function within `OnConnected` is not possible at this point. However, we can define a server hub method and immediately call that upon our connection `.done` callback. Then, in our new server method we can reallocate the logic you currently have in `OnConnected`.

This will change our setup quite a bit and introduce some additional steps, but observe the following example...

```
// WhateverHub
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    return base.OnConnected()
}

public void AfterConnected()
{
    // if(stuff) -- whatever if/else first user/last user logic
    // {
        Clients.Caller.hello("message")
    // }
}
```

---

```
var proxy= $.connection.whateverHub;

proxy.client.hello = function(message) {
    // last step in event chain
}

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    proxy.server.afterConnected() // call AfterConnected() on hub
});
```

So the basic idea here is to first

1. Connect => `.done(function() { ... });`
2. Call `server.afterConnected()`
3. Execute logic within that method
4. If we're satisfied with conditions call our `.hello()` client function

---

**Note** - this implementation is for a JavaScript client - but the same idea can be translated to a .net client. This is mostly an architectural issue.

Answer (score 1):

well... you are returning a task... so i think that may be the issue... 
you should first execute your code and then return the task... or put a ContinueWith... like...

```
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Task task = new Task(() =>
            {
                UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId, UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Count + 1);

                int amountOfConnections = UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Count;
                var lastConnection = UserHandler.ConnectedIds.OrderBy(x => x.Value).LastOrDefault();
                var allExceptLast = UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Take(amountOfConnections - 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

                if (amountOfConnections == 1)
                {
                    Clients.Client(UserHandler.ConnectedIds.First().Key).hello("Send to only(also first) one");
                }
                else
                {
                    Clients.Clients(allExceptLast).hello("Send to everyone except last");
                    Clients.Client(lastConnection.Key).hello("Send to only the last one");
                }
            });

        task.ContinueWith(base.OnConnected());

        return task;
    }
```

I haven't tested that... its just a guess..