# SignalR Send method not firing while trying to poll for existing connections

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using the latest version of SignalR with jQuery and getting some odd behavior where a user disconnects, but still hangs around in my "UserQueue" despite having disconnected.

I think this may be related to the fact that a page refresh appears to trigger the `OnDisconnected` and `OnConnected` events almost simultaneously. When I set a break point in one of these methods and step through, my pointer bounces back and forth between the two methods with each step (`F10`).

I'd like to run a check with each `OnConnected` event to find out who is actually connected to my app. I want to fire a JS event from my C# code in the OnConnected event, and then allow the client/front end to fire back a confirmation of the user being present:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    // Check for other users:
    Clients.All.checkForOtherUsers();

    // Do stuff with my user queue
    var curmodelId = GetModelId(Context);
    var curUserConnection = GetCurrentUser(Context);
    // First create the ledger is missing, setting the modelId as the first key
    if (_ledger == null)
    {
        _ledger = new ConnectionLedger(curmodelId, curUserConnection);
    }
    else
    {
        // key not found, create new connection pool this model
        if (!_ledger.PoolIds.Contains(curmodelId))
        {
            _ledger.AddConnectionPool(curmodelId, curUserConnection);
        }
        else
        {
            var curModelPool = _ledger.ConnectionPools.First(x => x.Id == curmodelId);
            curModelPool.UserQueue.Enqueue(curUserConnection);
        }
    }

    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

Now in the client JS, if I have this code:

```
modelHub.client.checkForOtherUsers = function () {
    // I can see logging here if I add console.log("checking for other users...")
    modelHub.server.send();
}
```

...I'm expecting my C# `Send` method to receive back the context (if the user is actually present at the client for the JS to execute) and update my `UserQueue`:

```
public void Send()
{
    var curmodelId = GetModelId(Context);
    var curModelPool = _ledger.ConnectionPools.First(x => x.Id == curmodelId);
    var curUserConnection = GetCurrentUser(Context);
    curModelPool.UserQueue.Enqueue(curUserConnection);
}
```

... but my `Send` method never gets fired, even when I fire it from the JS Console directly `$.connection.modelingHub.server.send()`.

***Why doesn't the Send method fire? Is there something about the order of events / async nature of the SignalR library that causes this?***

Comments on the overall design are welcome too (since I suspect it could be stupid), but note that I cannot access `Context.User` or `Clients.User` because of my customized Authentication config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be two causes below.

**Server-side**
Not good to call `Clients.All.checkForOtherUsers();` within `OnConnected()`.
I would recommend calling it after connected.

Please refer to [SignalR - Send message OnConnected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30362681)

**Client-side**
Might need to regist `modelHub.client.checkForOtherUsers = function () {` before calling start method.

> Normally you register event handlers before calling the start method
>   to establish the connection. If you want to register some event
>   handlers after establishing the connection, you can do that, but you
>   must register at least one of your event handler(s) before calling the
>   start method.
>  - [How to establish a connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)

Comment: Thanks for your input. The server part is already using that pattern. For the client, how do I "register event handlers before calling the start method" ?

Comment: It means follows. (I am not sure since I can't see your all client side code.)
`modelHub.client.checkForOtherUsers = function () { modelHub.server.send(); } $.connection.hub.start()`